# Is a one to one function also a total function

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

One of the lines in my lecture slides for theory of Computation states that

> A is equipotent to B (|A|=|B|) if there is bijection f: A->B

Which means that f is both one to one and onto. Since f is onto, it implies that the range(f) = B. 
So my question is that if a function is one to one, does it always mean that it's a total function i-e dom(f) = A ?
If not, then plz give an example.
Because if that is not the case then the aforementioned line cannot be sufficient to prove that A and B have the same cardinality.

Comment: Yes; see [Bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) : "In mathematics, a bijection, bijective function or one-to-one correspondence is a function between the elements of two sets, where **each element** of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set. There are **no** unpaired elements. "

Comment: When one writes $ f: A\to B$, that means that $A$ is the domain of the function: $ A=dom(f)$. I haven't heard of your terminology ("total function") before. I deduce that in general, when one speaks of functions, one means a "total function"!

Comment: @guestDiego - in Computability theory, [partial fucntions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), i.e. non-total functions, are used.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, thank you for the precisation. Actually I remember that a similar approach is used in the theory of unbounded operators in Banach space: one defines an operator $T:X\to Y$ whose domain is $D(T)\subset X$... To Danny, I can say that normally in set theory 'functions' are total functions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Thanks. I understand that. But my question is a one to one function always a total function?

Comment: See first comment above : "each element of one set is apired... There are no unpaired elements." **Each** means all...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  
Yes that is for bijection. Sorry if i am not phrasing it correctly. Consider I have a function which is one to one and NOT bijetctive. Now can i say that this function is total function?

Comment: Please, see [Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) : "The term one-to-one function must not be confused with one-to-one correspondence (aka bijective function), which uniquely maps all elements in both domain and codomain to each other." Maybe, we have a problem od communication...

Comment: In your question you have : "$A$ is *equipotent* to $B$ if there is *bijection* $f : A \to B$" and you asked : "is it the case that the aforementioned line cannot be sufficient to prove that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality ?" And the answer is : **NO**, a *bijection* is defined on **each** element of the domain, i.e. is *total*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the help. I got the answer. I realized that I am not good at asking questions. But that chat with you really helped me dig through and get the right answer.Really appreciate it.

Comment: It is not an issue of "not being able at asking questions"... It is only an issue of studying carefully the definitions; unfortunately, in some cases the terminology in use does not help.

Comment: Well, English is not my first language so i think that my question phrasing can be a bit obscure. And I agree with the terminology not being helpful sometimes.